How to Interpret Concordance Index Below 0.5 in Cross-Cohort Survival Analysis
I am conducting a survival analysis where I use cross-cohort validation for performance estimation (CV strategy can't be changed, its an external requirement). My metric of choice is the concordance index (C-index).
The cohorts I am working with are quite heterogeneous, and my model does not include any information about which cohort a given sample belongs to. This is intentional, mostly due to the cross cohort validation approach.
I’ve encountered an issue where, for some cohorts, the C-index is consistently below 0.5. Since 0.5 represents random predictions, values below this threshold suggest the model is performing worse than random—but at the same time, this might imply that reverting the predictions would yield better-than-random performance.
My questions are:

How can a C-index below 0.5 occur in this context? Could it be due to heterogeneity between cohorts, overfitting to training data, or some other reason?

Is this result valid or interpretable in a meaningful way? For example, does it suggest that the model is systematically misunderstanding the survival relationships in those specific cohorts?


For context, the models I’m using include:

RandomSurvivalForest
GradientSurvivalBoosting
(both implemented via the sksurv package in Python).

Any insights into the interpretation of a C-index below 0.5 in cross-cohort survival analysis, or potential issues with my methodology, is greatly appreciated!

Welcome to Cross Validated! It would help if you could edit the question to provide more information about your data and models: how many cases and events overall and within typical cohorts, how the cohorts are defined and used, details of how you implemented the random forest and boosted models, etc. Any of your suggestions might hold in principle, but it will be hard to know which applies in your case without more information. Specific examples of model results would also help. Please provide additional information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.
